# How to request from a SOAP webservice, convert the SOAP response to XML and compare it to another SOAP response, in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, automation

i am completely new in doing this 3 steps, so can you please help me step by step. (I understand Java language, did couple of scripts here and there but never touched SOAP stuff).
I need to do this:

1) Request from two SOAP services and store the responses in two objects.

2) Transform the response in XML(maybe, maybe not, depends if the output is in the form 
    < tag>< /tag> 
then no transformation required, but if it is 
    < n32:tag>< n32:tag> 
then i will want to get rid of "n32".

3) Compare those two responses and see where is the difference at node/tag and maybe inside tag level (maybe using XMLUnit)

4) Report the differences, in console.(not as an error in JUnit).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since you have the **webservice endpoint**, I sugest you to create webservice clients for each service.

You can do it with **wsimport**, that already comes with JDK:

```
wsimport.bat -d "D:\WS" -keep -verbose endpoint_ws.wsdl
pause
```

After this command, you will have java objects to access the webservice.

Put these objects in your project and access the webservice.

Here a reference on how to do:

[JAXWS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html)

2. Now that you have objects of the responses, you could code and compare each property.
   If there's a need to transform these objects into xml again for comparison (I say again because the SOAP message is already xml), you could use **xstream** (http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html).

---

**EDITED**

If you don't need to deal with the java client objects, you could follow this post:

[How to do a SOAP Web Service call from Java class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940234/how-to-do-a-soap-web-service-call-from-java-class)

In the second part of the post, is shown how to interact directly with the **request/response messages:**

```
import javax.xml.soap.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;

public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

    /**
     * Starting point for the SAAJ - SOAP Client Testing
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            String url = "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

            // Process the SOAP Response
            printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        String serverURI = "http://ws.cdyne.com/";

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);

        /*
        Constructed SOAP Request Message:
        <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:example="http://ws.cdyne.com/">
            <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
            <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                <example:VerifyEmail>
                    <example:email>mutantninja@gmail.com</example:email>
                    <example:LicenseKey>123</example:LicenseKey>
                </example:VerifyEmail>
            </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
         */

        // SOAP Body
        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("VerifyEmail", "example");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("email", "example");
        soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("mutantninja@gmail.com");
        SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("LicenseKey", "example");
        soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("123");

        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "VerifyEmail");

        soapMessage.saveChanges();

        /* Print the request message */
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        return soapMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Method used to print the SOAP Response
     */
    private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
    }

}
```

---

**EDITED**

To create a soap message directly from a string, first create a InputStream

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(send.getBytes());
SOAPMessage request = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
```

More info:

[How to convert a string to a SOAPMessage in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614508/convert-string-to-soap-in-java)

Comment: Isn't there an easier way? i just need to send the request to the WS endpoint and get the response.

Comment: Yes it helps, thanks. Where can i put my request message(multiple lines) ?

Comment: In the example given, the request message was constructed inside the createSOAPRequest() method.

Comment: See if the new info added helps.

Comment: Thanks but i used this in the end and it works, but it is very weird, sometimes i get the response and 80% i wont get it: http://tinyurl.com/oa3gurc

Comment: Hi edubriguenti, i used your sample and it works very nice, thank you. Do you know how to generate UsernameToken? i posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25939065/how-to-generate-usernametoken-for-soap-request