# Generate SOAP Message from java String

Tags: java, string, soap, saaj

I wrote method, which generate soap message from java string:

```
private SOAPMessage createRequest(String msg) {
    SOAPMessage request = null;
    try {
        MessageFactory msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        request = factory.createMessage();

        SOAPPart msgPart = request.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = msgPart.getEnvelope();
        SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

        StreamSource _msg = new StreamSource(new StringReader(msg));
        msgPart.setContent(_msg);

        request.saveChanges();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And, after that, I try generate some message. For example:

```
createRequest("test message");
```

But here - `request.saveChanges();` I catch this exception:
`com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message`

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You're not reading the whole exception stack, the most important part should be  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog, which means your msg should be valid XML in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string to a SOAPMessage in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614508/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-soapmessage-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are not passing a correct **protocol** formatted message.
Your code doesn't specify which SOAP protocol you want to use, that means it creates a message factory for SOAP 1.1 messages.

Thus, you would need to pass a correct SOAP1.1 message.
I replicated your method like this:

```
private static SOAPMessage createRequest(String msg) {
        SOAPMessage request = null;
        try {
            MessageFactory msgFactory = MessageFactory
                    .newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_1_PROTOCOL);
            request = msgFactory.createMessage();

            SOAPPart msgPart = request.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = msgPart.getEnvelope();
            SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

            javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource _msg = new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(
                    new java.io.StringReader(msg));
            msgPart.setContent(_msg);

            request.saveChanges();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return request;
    }
```

and I call it using this string:

```
String soapMessageString = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
createRequest(soapMessageString);
```

and It works.